# Why doesn't LiveReload work in Webpack when changing HTML if Hot Module Replacement is enabled?

Tags: javascript, webpack, layout, frontend, webpack-4

If you set `hot: true` in the `devServer` settings in **Webpack**, then the **Hot Module Replacement** for CSS works and the changes are applied without a complete page reload. But when changing HTML files, **LiveReload** for some reason does not work, you need to refresh the page manually so that the changes are applied.

If `hot: true` is disabled in the `devServer` configuration file, then when changing HTML files **LiveReload** works fine, the page reloads itself, but the **Hot Module Replacement** for CSS does not work, when changing CSS the page reloads completely.

Is this the way it should be? Why is this happening, how can I enable **Hot Module Replacement** for CSS, but at the same time make **LiveReload** work when changing HTML files?

To create many HTML files, I use the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` plugin.

Below are the configuration files:

**webpack.common.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = mode => {
const PRODUCTION = mode === 'production';

return {
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: 'img/[path][name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'img',
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            hash: false,
            template: 'src/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            PRODUCTION: PRODUCTION,
        }),
        new CopyPlugin([
            { from: 'src/img', to: 'img' },
            { from: 'src/fonts', to: 'fonts' },
        ]),
    ],
}
};
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {

return merge(common(argv.mode), {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        overlay: {
            warnings: true,
            errors: true
        },
        port: 8081,
        hot: true,
    },
    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 100,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    ],
});
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is still actual try the following with hmr enabled:

1. `npm i chokidar --save-dev`
2. add to webpack config file: `const chokidar = require('chokidar')`
3. add to webpack-dev-server options:

   ```
        before(app, server) {
            chokidar.watch([
                './build/**/*.html' //make sure to edit this path to your html files
            ]).on('all', function () {
                server.sockWrite(server.sockets, 'content-changed');
            });
        },
   ```

Comment: Yes, my question was relevant. Tried your advice, everything worked great, HMR is enabled and pages reload automatically when HTML changes. Thank you very much, you helped me out a lot!